# Evaluating the number 0 as an integer and/or a bool, and output the type for Pretty Printing

Tags: php

I am writing a "Pretty Printer" for use in a PHP application. The code works fine except for when a value is suppose to be an integer of 0.

For example.

```
$numbers = range('0', '9');
print_r($numbers);
```

You can see that index 0 has a value of 0

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 7
    [8] => 8
    [9] => 9
)
```

When I pretty print, 0 gets evaluated as a bool, and outputting double quotes. As per the ternary if statement, but I would like to output the ***ACTUAL*** value, while keeping the ability to output a blank string, IF the value is actually empty.

Now, I know that some people use 0 to indicate false, but since will be for my projects, I always use the *bool* designation for my actual *bool* values.

```
echo self::pp($numbers);

    0 : ""
    1 : 1
    2 : 2
    3 : 3
    4 : 4
    5 : 5
    6 : 6
    7 : 7
    8 : 8
    9 : 9
```

Further example, when I am using `false`;

```
$flagColors = ['Yellow'=>false,  'Red' => true, 'White'=>true, 'And'=>false, 'Blue'=>true];

echo self::pp($flagColors);
```

**Pretty Print Function**

```
public static function pp($arr){
            if (is_object($arr))
                $arr = (array) $arr;
            $retStr = '<ul style="list-style: none;">';
            if (is_array($arr)){
                foreach ($arr as $key=>$val){
                    if (is_object($val))
                        $val = (array) $val;
                    if (is_array($val)){
                        $retStr .= '<li><strong style="color: #0275d8";>' . $key . '</strong> :  <span >' . self::pp($val) . '</span></li>';
                    }else{
                        $retStr .= '<li><strong style="color: #0275d8";>' . $key . '</strong> : <span>' . ($val == '' ? '""' : $val) . '</span></li>';
                    }
                }
            }
            $retStr .= '</ul>';
            return $retStr;
        }
```

Other than adding multiple if statements checking if **$val** `is_numeric` or `is_bool`, or just `a value` is there a way to to kill 3 birds one stone?

Comment: did you see my answer? I'm curious, please can you tell me why you accepted the other answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it just be easier, and cleaner to read, to just add two extra `elseif`s?

Checking if `$val` is `is_numeric` first, (since you said you only use 0 for numbers and false for `bool`), then checking if the value is `is_bool`.

It gives you a cleaner codebase, AND the ability to format bools or numbers separately. So if you wanted numbers to show up in a different color you could.

```
public static function pp($arr){
            if (is_object($arr))
                $arr = (array) $arr;
            $retStr = '<ul style="list-style: none;">';
            if (is_array($arr)){
                foreach ($arr as $key=>$val){
                    if (is_object($val))
                        $val = (array) $val;
                    if (is_array($val)){
                        $retStr .= '<li><strong style="color: #0275d8";>' . $key . '</strong> :  <span >' . self::pp($val) . '</span></li>';
                    } elseif (is_numeric($val)){
                        $retStr .= '<li><strong style="color: #0275d8";>' . $key . '</strong> : <span>' . $val . '</span></li>';
                    } elseif (is_bool($val)){
                        $retStr .= '<li><strong style="color: #0275d8";>' . $key . '</strong> : <span>' . ($val  ? 'true' : 'false') . '</span></li>';
                    } else{
                        $retStr .= '<li><strong style="color: #0275d8";>' . $key . '</strong> : <span>' . ($val == '' ? '""' : $val) . '</span></li>';
                    }
                }
            }
            $retStr .= '</ul>';
            return $retStr;
        }
```

Comment: Instead of duplicate the `if`, it's better to create a dedicated function to do that, by doing so it can be used also in other script without duplicate the code.

Comment: This prints nothing for `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the value is `0` and it is an `int` by using the `===` operator (see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for the documentation), if so print `'0'`:

```
$val === 0 ? '0' : ($val == '' ? '""' : $val)
```

complete code:

```
public static function pp($arr){
            if (is_object($arr))
                $arr = (array) $arr;
            $retStr = '<ul style="list-style: none;">';
            if (is_array($arr)){
                foreach ($arr as $key=>$val){
                    if (is_object($val))
                        $val = (array) $val;
                    if (is_array($val)){
                        $retStr .= '<li><strong style="color: #0275d8";>' . $key . '</strong> :  <span >' . self::pp($val) . '</span></li>';
                    }else{
                        $retStr .= '<li><strong style="color: #0275d8";>' . $key . '</strong> : <span>' . printRealValue($val) . '</span></li>';
                    }
                }
            }
            $retStr .= '</ul>';
            return $retStr;
        }
}
```

Here is the dedicate function to handle the `$val` content:

```
public static function printRealValue($val)
{
    if(is_null($val))   return '!NULL'; // here set what you prefer to identify a null value
    if($val === 0)      return '0';
    if($val === true)   return 'true';
    if($val === false)  return 'false';
    return $val == '' ? '""' : $val;
}
```

By using a dedicated function, you can use the *code reusing* principle, that is one of OOP's base principles: the code will be more readable, maintainable and clean.

Comment: That doesn't account for `bool`. Which outputs `""` and `1`

Comment: @user-44651 see my edit, I added a new function to print the value

Comment: You'll have to check `bool` and probably `null` as `false` and `null` will `echo` as `0` and `true` will `echo` as `1`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I added the `null` case, anyway I already handle boolean by using the `===` operator. Isn't it true?